# laravel migration error while adding 2 foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I am using Laravel migrations to create my MySQL database, and have two tables papers and answers, and need to connect both tables using foreign keys. I have the `paper_id` as well as `question_no` as the foreign keys. but when adding foreign key I get an error. 
My migration for paper table and answer table

```
Schema::create('exampapers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('paper_id');
        $table->integer('question_no');
        $table->text('question');
        $table->string('answer1');
        $table->string('answer2');
        $table->string('answer3');
        $table->string('answer4');
        $table->integer('answerC');
        $table->string('knowarea');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->index(['paper_id','question_no']);

});

Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('paper')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('question')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('answers');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

and this is my code for creating foreign keys,

```
Schema::table('answers',function($table){
        $table->foreign('paper')->references('paper_id')->on('exampapers');
        $table->foreign('question')->references('question_no')->on('exampapers');
});
```

The error I get through php artisan is,

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 
>       Can't create table `exam_paper`.`#sql-b88_630` (errno: 150 "Foreign key 
>       constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `answers` add 
>       constraint `answers_paper_foreign`
>       foreign key (`paper`) references `exampapers` (`paper_id`))

I referred most of the other posts and already tried `unsignedInteger()` data type, running the table creation before foreign key creation.

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Have you first created `exampapers` table and then create `answers`? Also, add both foreign keys in `answers` table. Let me know if you don't understand!

Comment: @HirenGohel i did what you said still error,    Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `exam_paper`.`#sql-b88_63d` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `answers` add constraint `answers_paper_foreign` foreign key (`paper`) references `exampapers` (`paper_id`))

Comment: Add `$table->integer('paper_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();` and `$table->text('question')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();`

Comment: @HirenGohel thanks it works after adding `->nullable()->index()`

Comment: Glad i could help you!! I have posted my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `->unsigned()->nullable()->index();` in both column (i.e. in `paper_id` and in `question` in `exampapers` table).

Try to add like below in `exampapers` table:

```
$table->integer('paper_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
$table->integer('question_no')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
```

Now run `php artisan migrate` and problem fixed!

Hope this helps you!

Comment: @Naveed Sheriffdeen why did you choose this answer? 1. In the comments, you've shown the next error for a different table which means my solution clearly worked for your original problem. 2. `text('question')` has nothing to do with you FK constraint because you've referencing to `question_no` and not to `question`. 3. `nullable()` and `index()` have absolutely nothing to do with FK constraints.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin: I have updated my answer with `question_no` column which is FK. Also, you are right with your 3rd point and OP only needs `->unsigned()`. But as OP fixed problem, he choose my answer! Hope you understand! I don't have any problem if OP choose your answer too! :)

Comment: @Naveed and @Alexey: Use of `index()` as i understand: There is a small performance hit for the database server maintaining the index (it has to update the index when you write a record to the db) - so you usually use them only where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the key in the `exampapers` table unsigned too:

```
$table->integer('paper_id')->unsigned();
```

Or:

```
$table->insignedInteger('paper_id');
```

Or remove the `unsigned()` method from the foreign key definition:

```
$table->integer('paper');
```

Comment: if its unsigned i cant add data into it right so how will this help if i cant populate the exampapers table with the data. could you please explain with more details.

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen unsigned just means that you'll not be able to add negative integers like `-20`.

Comment: i added `unsigned()`  for both `paper_id` and `question_no` but still get error                                                                                 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `exam_paper`.`#sql-b88_647` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `answer` add constraint `answer_question_foreign` foreign key (`question`) references `exampapers` (`question_no`))

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen that's not related error for another foreign key from a different table you haven't shown.

Comment: There's a typo. It's not `insigned`, it's `unsigned`. But SO won't let me edit because "edits must be at least 6 characters"...

Answer (score 0):

I have made some edits to your migration code. Hope this will work

```
Schema::create('exampapers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('paper_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('question_no')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->text('question');
        $table->string('answer1');
        $table->string('answer2');
        $table->string('answer3');
        $table->string('answer4');
        $table->integer('answerC');
        $table->string('knowarea');
        $table->timestamps();
        //$table->index(['paper_id','question_no']);

    });

Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('paper')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('question')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('answers');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


Schema::table('answers',function($table){
        $table->foreign('paper')->references('paper_id')->on('exampapers');
        $table->foreign('question')->references('question_no')->on('exampapers');
    });
```